# add IOS frameworks & bundle to unity project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

i have `XCODE` project that implement speech recognition (OpenEars sdk).
i am wrapping this class for `UNITY3D`. `OpenEars`  gives me this folder that i must add to the project :

[image]

i have added the folder manually to the auto generated xcode project unity had build for me.
but now i want to know how can i tell unity to add this `Framework` folder automatically to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're doing this using a post-build script. We have a .cs file that resides under Assets/Editor (though I'm not sure that's a strict requirement). It has a static class with a method that is decorated with a [PostProcessBuild] attribute. From within that method we call a Python script that uses mod_pbxproj to modify the resulting .pbxproj file to include our framework, but perhaps there are also libraries in C# that can work with it (it's standard XML AFAIK).